# cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(id).keys doesn't actually contains all the keys?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

```kotlin
val camera = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(id)
```

`camera.keys` doesn't contain all the keys as it [should](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#getKeys()), for example is missing `FLASH_INFO_STRENGTH_MAXIMUM_LEVEL`

But I can retrive it by

```kotlin
camera.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_STRENGTH_MAXIMUM_LEVEL)
```

why in the world?

I also checked `getKeysNeedingPermission` even if it doens't have nothing to do with it.